# How to add js widget to shiny dashboard

Tags: javascript, plugins, shiny, shinydashboard

im trying to use linked in plugins with shiny, the plugins are in js

is there a way to add this plugin

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="IN/CompanyInsider" data-id="2896"></script>
```

to my shiny dashboard?
this is my dashboard code.

```
> library(shiny) library(shinydashboard)
> 
> ui <- dashboardPage(   dashboardHeader(title="Example"),  
> dashboardSidebar(
>     # Custom CSS to hide the default logout panel
>     tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-server-account { display: none; }'))),
>     # The dynamically-generated user panel
>     uiOutput("userpanel")   ),   dashboardBody(
>     box(),
>     box()
>         )
>     )
> 
> 
> server <- function(input, output, session) { }
> 
> shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out,

```
 fluidPage(width = 12, status = "primary",
collapsible = TRUE, solidHeader = TRUE,
tags$div(HTML('<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><script type="IN/CompanyInsider" data-id="2896" data-format="inline" data-width="1"></script'))),
```